# How to declare a method that takes a block as a callback

Tags: objective-c

I have a method that I'd like to call like so:

```
  void (^someblock)()=^{
    NSLog(@"I want to know");
  };
  [Item getCacheAndCallback:self.menuItemID andCallback:someblock];
```

How would I declare this in my header file? I have tried

```
  +(void)getCacheAndCallback:(int)menuItemID andCallback:(^());
```

but says "Expected a type". I thought this was supposed to go to void for type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 +(void)getCacheAndCallback:(int)menuItemID andCallback:(void(^)(void))completionBlock;
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting block types directly into method signatures can get messy as you've found. I would suggest you use a `typedef` to make it cleaner:

```
typedef void(^VoidBlock)();
```

Now you can write your block declaration as:

```
VoidBlock someBlock =  ^{ NSLog(@"I want to know"); };
```

and your method declaration as:

```
+ (void) getCacheAndCallback:(int)menuItemID andCallback:(VoidBlock)callBack;
```

*Note:* that `typedef` does not introduce a *new* type, just a shorthand. This means, for example, that you can declare a block using the full type (or even a different `typedef` with the same full type) and use it as `VoidBlock`.

Comment: thx for summary; I'll probably try both ways. I do iOS stuff only like 20% of time so things (esp block syntax) becomes fuzzy.

Answer (score 1):

Block syntax is weird. I keep this link handy to reference any time I happen to forget something: [fuckingblocksyntax.com](http://fuckingblocksyntax.com/)